# Make the mouse cursor stay visible while typing in NSTextField

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield

In OS X, the mouse cursor typically disappears when you are typing in a text field, in every app. Even when I am typing in this text field here on Stack Overflow, the cursor disappears.
This makes sense most of the time. But in my app I want it to stay visible, because the user has to do a lot of clicking between text fields, and it is really nasty when the mouse is always gone.

How can I make the cursor stay visible when typing in an `NSTextField`?

Comment: Doesn't your app support tabbing between fields? And if not, why not?

Comment: It Does. But anyway, beta testers found it annoying that the mouse was gone.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I solved it.

When you add a breakpoint at `+[NSCursor setHiddenUntilMouseMoves:]` you will notice, that it is called by `[NSTextField keyDown:]`
Apple says it is no good idea to override this method in order to prevent the mouse from disappearing. So I used NSTextFieldDelegate to get notified on `-(void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj` and `-(void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)obj`. Then I called `[NSCursor setHiddenUntilMouseMoves:NO]`

It is not 100% clean but it works.

Big thanks to Richard and Kurt for their great help :)

Answer (score 2):

It would be my guess that it is deep in apples code for the mouse to disappear when typing. Because even when you just start typing the mouse disappears, outside of a textbox even. Like when you click inside a browser window and type.

Comment: Not that deep. It's probably just calling [`+[NSCursor setHiddenUntilMouseMoves:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCursor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCursor/setHiddenUntilMouseMoves:). Try setting a breakpoint on that and see where it gets called from; it might give you an idea of where to call `[NSCursor setHiddenUntilMouseMoves:NO]`.